# Strange Requirejs behavior when loading Markdown

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a `requirejs` module in which I am trying to load `markdownjs`.  Here is the file:

```
define(function(require) {
  'use strict';

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var blogCollectionTemplate = require('hbs!app.templates/blog.collection.view');
  var BlogModelView = require('views/blog.item.view');
  var markdown = require('markdown');

  var BlogCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: blogCollectionTemplate,

    initialize: function() {
      debugger;
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template());
      this.renderAll();
      return this;
    },

    renderAll: function() {
      var that = this;
      this.collection.each(function(blog) {
        that.renderItem(new BlogModelView({model: blog}));
      });
    },

    renderItem: function(blog) {
      this.$el.find('#blog-posts').append(blog.render(blog).el);
    }
  });

  return BlogCollectionView;
});
```

Here is my `require.config`:

```
define(function() {

  require.config({
    hbs : {
      templateExtension : 'hbs',
      disableHelpers: true,
      disableI18n : true
    },

    shim: {
      'backbone': {
        deps: [
          'underscore',
          'jquery'
        ],
        exports: 'Backbone'
      },
      bootstrap: {
        deps: [ 'jquery' ]
      },
      DlHighlight: {
        exports: 'DlHighlight'
      },
      'jqueryMockAjax': {
        exports: '$.mockjax',
        deps: ['jquery']
      },
      json2 : {
        exports: "JSON"
      },
      'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
      }
    },

    paths: {

      backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone',
      bootstrap: 'libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap',
      DlHighlight: 'libs/hl/hl-all',
      highlight: 'libs/highlightjs/highlight.pack',
      jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
      jqueryMockAjax: 'libs/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax',
      markdown: 'libs/markdown/lib/markdown',
      text: 'libs/text/text',
      underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',

      hbs: 'libs/hbs/hbs',
      handlebars: 'libs/hbs/Handlebars',
      i18nprecompile: 'libs/hbs/hbs/i18nprecompile',
      json2 : 'libs/hbs/hbs/json2',

      'app.templates': '../templates/'
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the strange behavior.  In my `initialize`, when I hit the debugger, I have access to the `markdown` object that I have imported, BUT if I have try to use the `markdown` object, then it is always `undefined`.  If I put `markdown` in the `initialize` or in one of the `render` methods, the `markdown` variable is `undefined`.  It makes no sense, but is there some behavior that I dont understand about `requirejs`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which markdown module are you trying to load? If it is a third party module, a link would be appropriate.

Comment: I am trying to load [this](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) `markdown` module, but any will work for me.

Comment: Thanks. That module is AMD-aware so it should work. I'm thinking there is something incorrect in the configuration you pass to RequireJS. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: I added the config, but remember that if I put a `debugger` in the initialize block and I just import `markdown` I have access.  It is only when I try to use `markdown` in the module that it is `undefined`.

Comment: The config helps. How did you install markdown-js in the location where you use it? npm, bower, download + grunt build, download one of their tgz bundles?

Comment: `bower install` and as you see I just referenced the location my `config.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the code of a bower installation of markdown-js, I found that what bower installs won't work with RequireJS as-is. Try adding this shim:

```
"markdown": {
    exports: "markdown"
}
```

As to why were you able to get a value for `markdown` in the debugger without the shim, I believe you were getting it (perhaps without realizing it) from the global scope. Markdown-js installs itself into the global scope (`window.markdown`, which is then accessible as `markdown` if no other variable interferes with it) when it is loaded. This is speculation but it fits the facts.

Comment: That worked.  Why would it work at all without the shim?  When I would hit my `debugger` statement, I was able to access `markdown` without the shim.

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I guess I would have never guessed this because I assumed his use of `backbone` also exported to `Backbone` in the global scope. :-P

Answer (score 1):

You can require all of those modules in the `define` clause itself:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'hbs!app.templates/blog.collection.view',
    'views/blog.item.view',
    'markdown'
], function (
    Backbone,
    blogCollectionTemplate,
    BlogModelView,
    markdown
) {
    'use strict';

    // do stuff
});
```

Also, what do you mean by "If I put markdown in the initialize or in one of the render methods"? Do you mean actually explicitly requiring markdown in initialize and render? Is there any reason to not just load markdown in the `define` clause as labeled above?

If you are explicitly requiring markdown in initialize or render, I am not sure why that would return `undefined`, but let me know if moving requirements to the `define` clause fixes your issue (or if you can't do that). Perhaps you could post the code in the `markdown` module (if it's not a library that is)?

Comment: What i meant by putting `markdown` in the `initialize` or `render` methods is I would import `markdown` at the top like normal, but when I tried to use the reference `markdown`, it would then be undefined at the same `debugger` statement where before it was defined.  I changed my `define` statement to load the modules like you show above and the same exact thing happened, my `markdown` was `undefined` in my `initialize` function.

Comment: Ah I see. I'll keep this answer around in case a require-noobie stumbles upon it.